# Globbing pattern to include all files in the intermediate folder

Tags: typescript, unix, karma-runner, glob

I'm configuring typescript/karma and I need to match all files inside a directory using globbing pattern.

Suppose I have the following directory structure:

```
src
  webapp
     core
     ext
     libs
```

So now I want to match all files in the `libs` folder without specifying full path to the folder. Is this the correct globbing pattern:

```
**/webapp/libs/**
```

This is for [typescript configuration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html):

> The "files" property takes a list of relative or absolute file paths.
>   The "include" and "exclude" properties take a list of **glob-like file
>   patterns**. The supported glob wildcards are:
>
> - matches zero or more characters (excluding directory separators) ? matches any one character (excluding directory separators)
>     **/ recursively matches any subdirectory

Comment: What shell, if done on the command line? Or, what library if done programmatically? Different interfaces have different globbing support.

Comment: it's not shell, it's typescript/karma configuration. sorry for not adding it in the first place. I have added it now

Comment: According to the documentation you pointed to, `src/web/libs/**/*`

Comment: @TomRegner, yeah, but I don't want to specify full path.

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com Why not, may I ask? The documentation suggests `**/web/libs/**/*` then, or a variation thereof

Comment: @TomRegner, because the directory structure I showed is just an example. The level nesting can be much deeper. This one is wrong - `**/web/libs/**/*`. Probably what @lathspell suggested is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "webapp" in your directory structure :) Maybe you want something like this?

```
$ find . -wholename "**/web/libs/*"
./src2/web/libs/t
./src2/web/libs/tt
./src/web/libs/ttt
```

Comment: sorry for not mentioning it, it's not to be used in the shell

Comment: no problem, syntax should be almost the same, 1 star for an directory entry and 2 stars for any number of directories.

Comment: thanks. will that match the files inside subdirectories of `libs`?

Comment: no, only entries directly under libs/. You need "**/web/libs/*/*" for entries in exactly one level below "web/libs" or "**/web/libs/**/*" for entries in arbitrary deep structures below "web/libs".

Comment: thanks. why did you use one asterisk instead of 2 only in the last examples?